# Close ActiveUIDocument using Revit API(2014) from Idling Event Handler

Tags: autodesk, revit-api, revit

Is there any way to close ActiveUIDocument using Revit API? I have created a separate addin to close the ActiveUIDocument which works from the Revit GUI but when i try to call that addin from Idling event handler, nothing happens. Please help.

Below is the code for my addin:

```
private void CloseDoc(object obj)
{
     SendKeys.SendWait("^{F4}");
}

public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementSet elements)
{
     Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Close));
     return Result.Succeeded;      
}
```

Code used to call addin from within Idling event handler :

```
     RevitCommandId id_built_in = RevitCommandId.LookupPostableCommandId(PostableCommand.SheetIssuesOrRevisions);
     RevitCommandId addinID = RevitCommandId.LookupCommandId("1869A8A1-A239-41CF-9A79-96234D92DEF4");
     app.PostCommand(addinID);
```

Addinn Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RevitAddIns>
  <AddIn Type="Command">
    <Assembly>AddinExternalLauncher.dll</Assembly>
    <ClientId>1869A8A1-A239-41CF-9A79-96234D92DEF4</ClientId>
    <FullClassName>AddinExternalLauncher.AddinLauncher</FullClassName>
    <Text>Addin External Launcher</Text>
    <Description></Description>
    <VisibilityMode>AlwaysVisible</VisibilityMode>
    <VendorId>ADSK</VendorId>
    <VendorDescription>Autodesk, www.autodesk.com</VendorDescription>
  </AddIn>
</RevitAddIns>
```

Last few lines of Journal Output after calling addin:

```
' 1:< total bytes expanded: 35414988 
' 1:< ;EES;0;0;86;0;0;0;0;0;14; 
' 1:<  0 ModelServerState "Destroyed": Current server = "Not Queried", Model server = "", Model server state = "Not Applicable" 
' 1:<   System (MB) [Available /  Total ]  [Revit Memory Usage (MB)   ] 
' 1:< RAM Statistics:     3385 /     8040       623=InUse      629=Peak  
' 1:< VM  Statistics:  8384617 /  8388607       536=InUse      542=Peak  
 ' 1:< ::9:: Delta VM: Avail -13 -> 8384597 MB, Used +28 -> 564 MB, Peak +21 -> 564 MB; RAM: Avail -26 -> 3360 MB, Used +41 -> 664 MB, Peak +36 -> 665 MB 
 'E 24-Aug-2016 15:02:28.961;   1:< 
 ' [Jrn.File Input Information] COMMON.FILE_INPUT.FILE_TYPE: .rvt 013144064.000000
' 0:< The Idling event callback used 53 seconds 
' 3:< ::10:: Delta VM: Avail -20 -> 8384577 MB, Used +6 -> 570 MB, Peak +6 -> 570 MB; RAM: Avail -2 -> 3358 MB, Used +3 -> 667 MB, Peak +1 -> 667 MB 
'  0.114085      4:<<From Parking Area: ;PERF;MISC;generating greps 
' 0:< ::10:: Delta VM: Avail +5 -> 8384583 MB, Used -13 -> 558 MB; RAM: Avail +2 -> 3361 MB, Used -7 -> 661 MB, Peak +0 -> 668 MB 
'  0.372841   1:<<;PERF;MISC;drawing/ALL_GAPS   0.258756/TurnOff_GAPs 74% 
'C 24-Aug-2016 15:02:29.386;   0:< idle0_doc 
'H 24-Aug-2016 15:02:29.386;   0:< 
Jrn.Directive "AllowPressAndDrag"  _
        , 1
' 0:< <<Begin build CT>>
'
'Edit mode: IDR_COMMON
'Command: ID_BUTTON_SELECT
'Category: 0
'Bar list: 
'   Dialog_Revit_DynamicLabelDBar
'   Dialog_Essentials_FilterSelectionNew
'Presenter list: 
'   PP_DebugTab_Binding_Demo
'Product: Architecture
'
'
'***********************************************************
'***********************************************************
'<<End build CT>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not directly call your method from the Idling handler?

```
private void ApplicationOnIdling(object sender, IdlingEventArgs idlingEventArgs)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Close));
}
```

And while you're at it, why not use a Task instead of ThreadPool?

```
Task.Run(() => SendKeys.SendWait("^{F4}"));
```

It accomplishes the same thing, and is cleaner than having an extra method with an unused parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Directly calling SendKeys from Idling event handler crashed the revit application not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Of course nothing happens when you call an external command from the Idling event handler.

The Idling event handler executes while Revit has nothing else to do.

If your command has to be executed, Revit has something ton do, and therefore the Idling event handler cannot be working.

The proper and only way to programmatically trigger the execution of an external command is via the PostCommand functionality:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/10/programmatic-custom-add-in-external-command-launch.html

I like cs1088's answer above and hope that solves the issue for you.